# Facebook share kit ios

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, sharekit

I have implemented Facebook share kit to my app and it works as intended, but if the user installed Facebook official iPhone app it messes up my app because it logins through Facebook iPhone app instead of share kit default login. Is there way to make share kit ignore Facebook official iPhone app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such method. You just have to use the latest Facebook API provided by the Apple. That may solve your problem of not detecting the login from app.